# How will increasing each memory allocation size by a fixed number of bytes affect heap fragmentation?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have `operator new()` replaced in my C++ program so that it [allocates a slightly bigger block to store extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134195/how-do-i-call-the-original-operator-new-if-i-have-overloaded-it). So the program performs exactly the same set of allocations except that now it requests several bytes more memory in each allocation. Otherwise its behavior is completely the same and it processes exactly same data. The program allocates lots of blocks (millions, I suppose) of various sizes during its runtime.

How will increasing each allocation size by a fixed number of bytes (same for every allocation) affect heap fragmentation?

Comment: The native malloc/new implementaion will already do this for you. Heap allocators are pretty sophisticated already so trying to make an optimization like this is likely going to make things worse.

Comment: @Mike Weller: Where am I doing an optimization?

Comment: Well why have you made this change?

Comment: @Mike Weller: I need this to track allocations and simplify memory leaks detection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your program uses some "edge" block sizes (say, near to a power of two), I don't see that block size (or a small difference in block size compared to the program with standard allocation) may affect fragmentation. With millions of allocation, a good allocator fills up the space and manages it efficiently.

Thinking the other way around, imagine your program originally used the blocks of the sizes the same as the one with the modified allocator. Would you then bother about memory fragmentation in that case?

Answer (score 1):

If your blocks (allocated and deallocated memory) are still smaller that a C library allocator handles without problems with fragmentation than you must not face any memory fragmentation. For example take a look at my own question about allocators: [Small block allocator on Linux (or RedHat Linux) to avoid memory fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415373/small-block-allocator-on-linux-or-redhat-linux-to-avoid-memory-fragmentation).

In other words. You have implented your own ::operator new() and in it you call `malloc()` and pass a slighly bigger block size. `malloc()` is in a C library and it is responsible not only for allocating and deallocating but also for avoiding memory fragmentation. If you do not frequently allocate and free blocks with sizes bigger than the allocator can handle efficently then you can expect that there will be on memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

Heaps are normally implemented as linked lists of cell. On application startup there is only one large cell. Your first allocation breaks off a small piece at the beginning to create a new allocated heap cell. Subsequent allocations do the same. After a while some cells are freed leaving free holes between allocated block.

After running a while, when you request an allocation, the allocator walks the heap until it finds a free cell of equal size to that requested or bigger. Rounding up to larger cell allocation sizes may require more memory up front but increases the likelyhood of finding a suitable free cells meaning that new memory does not have to be added to the end of the heap. This may improve performance.

However, bear in mind heap operations are expensive and therefore should be minimized. You are most probably allocating and deallocating objects of the same type and therefore same size. Look into using specialized free lists for your object. This will save the heap operation and thus mimimize fragmentation. The STL has allocators for this very reason.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation driving the memory allocator, for instance:
On widows, it pulls memory from the process heap, under under XP, this heap its not set to be the low fragmentation implementation, which could really throw a spanner in the works.

Under a bin or slab based allocator, your few extra bytes might push it up to the next block size, wasting memory madly and causing horrible virtual memory thrashing.

Depending on your memory usage needs, you might be better served by using a custom allacator to replace `::new`, something like hoard or nedmalloc.